# Is $f$ differentiable at $0$? and if it is what is the value of $f'(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

I'm studing that if  $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \phantom{2}$ is a function that  verifies :

$\exists\, K \in \mathbb{R^+}, \phantom{1}\forall\, x,y \in \mathbb{R}: \lvert f(y)-f(x) \rvert \le K\lvert \cos y - \cos x \rvert \Rightarrow f$ is a Lipschitz function

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}:f(x + 2\pi) = f(x)$

Then f is differentiable at $0$

The exercise seems easy but I'm not sure how can I prove it, any suggestions?And if it's differentiable what's the value of $f'(0)$?

Comment: Well, that's not my homework, it's just i like to do sometimes maths and as my level is so low I like to ask people who knows more than me

Comment: I really tried this exercises a days ago and I'm sure that for most of people are trivial but it is not for me

Comment: @CameronWilliams if you still thinking that that's my homework you can just ignore this post

Comment: The formatting is awkward (maybe it's the mobile version). Are you asking if a function is Lipschitz and periodic is then differentiable at zero?

Comment: @Icv yeah but i think its not neccesary to use both conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use identity
$$
\cos x - \cos y = -2 \sin \frac{x+y}{2}\cdot \sin\frac{x-y}{2}
$$
to obtain the estimate (say, WLOG $x\ge y$, so we can use $|\sin \alpha| \le \alpha$ for positive $\alpha$)
$$
|f(x) - f(y)| \le 2K \left| \sin \frac{x-y}{2} \cdot \sin \frac{x+y}{2}\right| \le K|x-y|\left|\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\right|
$$

Can you now prove that $f$ is Lipschitz and establish differentiability at zero?

Comment: Since $-1 \le \sin (\frac{x + y}{2}) \le 1 \Rightarrow \forall\, x,y \in \mathbb{R}: |f(x) - f(y)|  \le K|x-y|\left|\sin\frac{x+y}{2}\right| \le K|x-y| \Rightarrow$ f is a Lipschitz function

Comment: But I'm still confused in how can I establish differentiability at zero

Comment: @jackesgamero use definition of derivative and the proved inequality with $x = h, y=0$, where $h$ is sufficiently small